# cin does not accept input properly

Tags: c++, input, runtime

I use the following code to get the input

```
int main() {
    int x=0,value=0;
    cin>>x;
    string str;
    for(int i=0;i<x;++i){
      cin>>str;
      value = findpalindrome(str);
      cout<<value<<endl;}
  return 0;
}
```

And these are my test cases:

```
3
xabcbayabbaz
abcbaabc
abcba
```

The code accepts the first string and gives the output. However, when I enter the next two strings, it just waits for more input. I tried giving input separately without the loop but that didn't work either. The compiler waits for more input infinitely.

I am putting my entire code here for reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct palindrome{
  int start;
  int end;
  int strlength;
}s[20];

bool checkifpalindrome(string str)
{
    string str1=str;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length()/2;++i){
        char temp=str1[i];
        str1[i]=str1[str.length()-1-i];
        str1[str.length()-1-i]=temp;
        
    }
    if(str1.compare(str)==0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
bool checkoverlap(int cur_pos,int prev_pos){
  if((s[cur_pos].start>=s[prev_pos].start && s[cur_pos].start<=s[prev_pos].end)||
    (s[cur_pos].end>=s[prev_pos].start && s[cur_pos].end<=s[prev_pos].end))
    return true;
  else 
    return false;
}

int findmax(int count){
    int max = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<count;++i){
        if (s[i].strlength>max){
            max = s[i].strlength;
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
int findpalindrome(string str)
{
    int sum=0;
    int count=-1;
    string str1;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();++i){
    for(int j=1;j<str.length()-i+1;++j){
        str1=str.substr(i,j+1);
        if(checkifpalindrome(str1)){
            count++;
            s[count].start=i;
            s[count].end=i+j;
            s[count].strlength=str1.length();
        }  
      }
    }
    int pos[2];
    pos[0]=findmax(count);
    sum+=s[pos[0]].strlength;
    s[pos[0]].strlength=0;
    pos[1]=findmax(count);
    int i=0,n=10;
    while(i<n){
        if(s[pos[0]].strlength==str.length())
          break;
        else if(checkoverlap(pos[1],pos[0])){
          s[pos[1]].strlength=0;
          pos[1]=findmax(count);
          continue;
        }
        else if(s[pos[1]].strlength==0)
            break;
        else{
          sum+=s[pos[1]].strlength;
          break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
int main() {
    int x=0,value=0;
    cin>>x;
    string str;
    for(int i=0;i<x;++i){
      cin>>str;
      value = findpalindrome(str);
      cout<<value<<endl;}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the issue is anything to do with `cin` for the *second* input. Just call `findPalindrome` with the input that doesn't work. My guess is you're going into an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: Run in a debugger (or add some print statements) to see where you code is blocking.

Comment: Recommended reading: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/10147399)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `i++` line in the `while` loop of your `findpalindrome` function will **never** be executed - either the loop will exit (on `break`) or start again from the beginning (on continue).

Removing the `continue;` line from the first `else if` block in that loop prevents the program from going into an infinite loop - but I can't verify that it fixes *all* your problems (there are numerous cases of comparing signed to unsigned types, which *may* be problematical).

Enabling (full) compiler warnings (and heeding them) is helpful in such circumstances! For your original code, **clang-cl** gives (among other things):

> warning : code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Adrian Mole's answer, it is good to check such things by removing intermediate functions like your `findpalindrome()`, just to make sure, that input values are read correctly and the problem is not in it.

Comment: I think this is more suitable as a comment than an answer.